# Graphic scrolling in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone

I have a graphic that is 3 times the width of an iphone landscape view.
I am trying to auto scroll it so that it appears that it is moving sideways, without using the touchscreen scrolling method.
My aim is to maybe have a button you can press and it moves it left or right across the screen like an animation.
I can deal with everything else but am having trouble finding a solution.
Any example code would be appreciated or even any info on whether it is possible or not.
Thanks. Dave

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap a `UIView` in an [animation block](http://objcolumnist.com/2009/07/18/simple-uiview-based-animations-on-the-iphone/). The animation sweeps the origin value in its `frame` property from one point to another, over a set period of time.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.
I dont think this is what i'm after though.
I am looking to scroll the graphic from end to end without having to cut it frame by frame manually.
Any sample code or any information on how to do that will be appreciated.
If UIView will work, please let me know how.
Thanks again.
Dave

Comment: You don't cut it manually, you just specify the start and end frame origins, the time period and type of the animation, and the block takes care of the rest.